# How do I fix 'Missing operator' error when changing file names with command line?

Tags: for-loop, command-line, file-rename, batch-rename

I'm new to command line and trying to change a bunch of file names. I keep getting the error message "Missing operator."

My code:

```
set /a counter=1 for %i in ("C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Thumbnails\AF070?.jpg")do (ren "%~i" "af01900%counter%.jpg" set /a counter+=1)
```

Thoughts?

This is the result I'm looking for:

AF0704.jpg > af019003.jpg,
AF0705.jpg > af019004.jpg, AF0706.jpg > af019005.jpg,
etc.

Thanks for helping out!